# Mvc4 Website builds, but Error List is populated when viewing Razor files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have an Mvc4 website that builds and runs just fine, but each Razor content page is filled with errors when viewed in VS2012.  I get errors that the `model` keyword and ViewBag object don't exist, and Intellisense only picks up code like `Html.TextBox` and `Html.Hidden`, not `Html.HiddenFor` or `Html.TextBoxFor`.

My guess would be that nothing in the  node of Web.Config is being registered by intellisense; does anyone know how to get these namespaces to properly register again?

Comment: are they registered in the web.config `namespaces` section?

Comment: Can you add the view code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with no specified version in the Views/Web.config.  Here's what the updated config sections look like now:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```